# How to find out where the intent is from in onStartCommand() Android service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

In my application, I have a service which can be started by several Activities, other Services or other Java classes.

Is there any way, in the service's `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` to find out from which sender the intent is from except for using `putExtras()` to include the sender's information for every single `startService()` call in my app?

Comment: It's been three years since this question was asked. Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No way to achieve this @BajajG, the activity have to explicitly set a bundle parameter carrying its name

Comment: Thanks, I used a "name" field in each intent and checked the contents of the received intent using `intent.toUri(0)`. As you said, there is no better way to achieve this.